# How to remove an object from data array (core data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, core-data

I have a table view with sections. when I try to delete a row from the table view i get the following error.........

*'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 5.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'*

After some online research I understand that I have to remove the object from the array. 
I am using core data with standard managedObjectContext and fetchedResultsController. I don't understand what is the array here. 
Can someone help please.

Here is the code for number of section and number of rows....

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger count = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
    return count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    NSInteger count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    return count;
}
```

Below is the code I am using to delete a row....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
        NSManagedObject *birthdayToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:birthdayToDelete];

        // Update the array and table view.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        // Commit the change.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    [_birthdayTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `numberOfRowsInSection` implementation ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my questions with more codes.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with NSFetchResultsController but i'd say you should refresh self.fetchedResultsController or execute the request again. How do you create it in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];` if you are using `NSFetchResultsController` delegate methods. Implement the following: These will get called after you save your `managedObjectContext` post deletion. (remember to set the delegate of your `NSFetchedResultsController`. Also, DONT call `[tableView reloadData];`. It will make the animation skip and look weird :-) This is the beauty of using `NSFetchedResultsController`, it does the heavy lifting for you and listens out for changes on the `managedObjectContext`

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
       switch(type) {
         case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
             [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
             [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
     switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
     [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: managed to animate the updates. just changed the UITableViewRowAnimationNone to UITableViewRowAnimationFade.

Comment: That's the one. There are a few different animations you can use.

Answer (score 0):

this usually results from the number of items in your array disagreeing with the number returned from `numberOfRowsInSection:` Make sure you're calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` correctly when you edit.

Comment: that is the question I am asking, how can I update the array (or remove object from the array)